# Memoize dependencies within a custom react hook is anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm encounter myself writing a **custom hook that exposes a socket connection**, the fact is that the code is there and it is working but I have the following API.

```
const socket = useWebSocket(
  companyId,
  accessToken,
  resourceUrl,
  !settings.data.manualDispatch,
  options
);
```

The hook encapsulate several things:

1. Authenticate the WebSocket connection by asking first for a ticket that is appended to the WebSocket url *(so it actually does a first HTTP request that returns a ticket and then trigger other effect that create a connection and update the socket state that is being return)*
2. As I mentioned previously it does a request GET to a ticket and create a WebSocket connection
3. Cleanup any existing WebSocket connection when a new one is created *(through state management)*

**The problem is:**

I am **currently** using a reference within the hook to avoid create new objects and ending up in an infinite loop BUT **It will be that consider an anti-pattern?**.

**Use memo alongside the hook?**
Yes sure is valid approach but I feel like I am forcing the developers using my hook to write the same code over and over *(memoize the options before pass it to the hook)*.

**In summary:**

**OPTION 1:**

Don't memoize the options to use the hook and do that process within the hook (because options are made of things that are not mean to change, urls and callbacks).

```
   const socket = useWebSocket(
        companyId,
        accessToken,
        resourceUrl,
        !settings.data.manualDispatch,
        {
            onMessageCallback: message => {
                // do things with message
            },
            onUnexpectedCloseCallback: () => {
                // do things on close
            },
            url: websocketUrl,
        }
    );
```

**OPTION 2:**

We memoize the options in order to use the hook **because the option 1 is an anti-pattern**.

```
    const options = useMemo(
        () => ({
            onMessageCallback: message => {
                // do things with message
            },
            onUnexpectedCloseCallback: () => {
                // do things on close
            },
            url: websocketUrl,
        }),
        [websocketUrl]
    );

    const socket = useWebSocket(
        companyId,
        accessToken,
        resourceUrl,
        !settings.data.manualDispatch,
        options
    );
```

Comment: I'm unsure wether the socket should be a `use` at all. I'd rather go with a Context that exposes the underlying socket, and then defining some hooks that depend on it, i.e. `const isOnline = useSocketState(socket)`

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks for taking the time on answering. What happen if we have several connections? Or what happen if you want to be reactive to the state of the socket? For instance, we currently show notifications if the socket was unexpectedly closed.
That's why I choose the hook I guess. Nevertheless, super open to any changes if this is consider an anti-pattern. (which is the core of the question)

Comment: E.g. `const errors = useSocketErrors(socket);`. Several connections can be managed using different Contexts, but I can't think of a case were you would use multiple sockets

Comment: Seems simple enough to me. If given the same inputs to your hook function, do you expect the output to be the same? If so, then why not memoize [the results of] the inputs?  You could even factor your hook code to take in a dependency array much like the built-in react hooks in order to do value comparisons.

Comment: What if you want to change the handler if something completely unrelated to the socket changes? You'd do `const handler = useMemo(..., [otherStuff])` ... What will happen? Right, that handler will never be called, as you memoize it internally in a way that no one will notice it, in other words maintenance nightmare

Comment: Thanks for jump in too @DrewReese nevertheless, indeed I am memoizing the input because I am expecting the same output, BUT the key concept is the fact that I am "hiding" that memoization within the hook instead doing so outside of it.

With that in mind, I think that also what JonasWilms mention may makes sense in the fact that hiding that can make it more difficult to maintain.

Comment: Can you clarify why you worry option 1 is an antipattern so we know why you're trying to avoid memoizing your websocket callbacks inside your custom hook? I also believe it is better to write a generic onMessage websocket event than to need to change your handlers repeatedly through the life of a single socket connection, that's a code smell to me. Why would the functionality need to change?